# Opening files created in windows 7

Tags: windows

I have nvq work i done on windows I have now put them on Linux what app do i need to read them please. I havent done anything as im 100% new to this and im finding it very very complicated

Comment: What software did you use to create/edit it on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

In all recent versions of Ubuntu, you should see your partitions in the dock on the left. Note that the partition on which Windows was present will be called "200 GB Volume" or something like that. Just click on the relevant partition, and you'll be able to browse it, and go to whatever folder your work is located.

Comment: I forgot to say I put the files on a usb stick...sorry I'm new to this